# How do you update your UI when using a state machine

Tags: swift, callback, state-machine, gameplay-kit

I'm using `swifts` `stateMachine` from `gamePlayKit`. It works great, but there is one thing I don't understand: The `stateMachine`seems to be its own isolated island; from what I can tell there is no way to pass in `arguments` or get `callbacks`. And this raises questions like, how do I update the UI?

Lets say I enter combat state:

```
 stateMachine.enter(CombatState.self)
```

There's no way to pass in an `argument`. Ok, fine. But then CombatState does its thing and when it's done it goes into another state. BUT, before that I need a `callback` to the `view` so that I can remove the units from the board lost in combat like so:

```
self.removeChildren(in: nodesOutOfAction)
```

But there's no way to send the `nodes` out of the `stateMachine` because there's no possible way to add a `completion handler`. So how do you work around this problem? To me the `stateMacine` is pointless as it can´t update the UI.

Its possible to access `properties` of the state like so:

```
stateMachine.enter(CombatState.self)
self.removeChildren(in: combatState.nodesToRemove)
```

But that can't be safe, right? Still, as this is the only option that I know of, this is how I solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I totally recommend you check the [DemoBots project from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/DemoBots/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015179).

You should pass the entity reference on the `State Initializer`

For example

```swift
class CombatState: GKState {

    unowned var gameScene: GameScene

    required init(gameScene: GameScene) {
        self.gameScene = gameScene
    }

    override func didEnter(from previousState: GKState?) {
        gameScene.removeChildren(in: ...)
    }
}
```

With this logic you can decouple a lot of logic inside to the states.

Comment: Ah, perfect, just what I was looking for! Thanks alot for providing this @Maetschl I'll definately make sure to chack that project as well! :D

Comment: Don't forget approve the answer if it was a solution :) @JoakimSjöstedt